# Reading numbers in Python - 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with the code. I have a sort algorithm and I check it for a specific input.
As input, the number of tests 1 <= d <= 100, the integer 0 <n <= 214748364 and n numbers from the range -2147483646 <= a_k <= 2147483647.
Input:

```
3
8 5 2 6 4 1 3 2 6
8 2 4 5 6 1 3 2 6
8 1 6 2 7 3 8 4 5
```

My code:

```
# Bubble Sort

d = int(input()) #number of tests
#A = []
def wczytanie_liczb():
    for k in range(0,d):
        n = input() #number of digits in the string
        n = int(n)
        A = []
        for l in range(0,n):
            m = input() #fill in the array
            m = int(m)
            A.append(m)
        #print(A)
        bubble_sort(A)

def bubble_sort(A):
    i = 0
    zam = True
    while i < len(A)-1 and zam:
        j = 0
        zam = False
        while j < len(A) - 1 - i:
            if A[j] > A[j+1]:
                A[j], A[j+1] = A[j+1], A[j]
                zam = True
            j +=1
    #print(A)
        
wczytanie_liczb()
```

it gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 28, in <module>
  File "./prog.py", line 9, in wczytanie_liczb
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: what inputs are you giving?

Comment: can you add a `print(m)` just after accepting the input, and let us know what it outputs?

Comment: Not getting any errors from this code...

Comment: This program must pass through the checker. They give that inputs and when i check it on ideone.com I get this error

Comment: The stdin values on ideone must be one value per line, not space seperated.

Answer (score -2):

Conclusion. The “TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer” error is raised when you pass a string as an argument into a range() statement. To fix this error, make sure all the values you use in a range() statement are integers

Comment: The OP is, every variable used within a range is (attempted to be) cast as an integer.

Comment: If the range was giving the error, it would have shown up on line 3 where he converts the input to int. Its the conversion a few lines later that is giving the error.

Comment: To fix this error, make sure all the values you use in a range() statement are integers

Comment: ok I understand, i want to use only integers and as input I have integers.. but I don't know why ideone.com shows me such errors

Comment: Can you please add screenshot in question